# Text flickering when using LinkMovementMethod

Tags: android, textview

I'm using `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` on a `TextView` instance but the text is flickering when touched. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@android:color/primary_text_dark_nodisable` or `android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable` as the text color of your text view. You can do this either in XML:

```
<TextView
  android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
/>
```

or programmatically:

```
textView.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_dark_nodisable));
```

Comment: [Resources#getColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29) only returns the default color from a complex [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html). So in the given example it wouldn't matter if you used primary_text_dark or primary_text_dark_nodisable. To get the ColorStateList you should use [Resources#getColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList%28int%29) instead.